# Can regex.sub (re.sub) be used for nested expressions?

Tags: python, regex, replace, templating

I'm trying to extend my little templating engine to support nested "variable expressions".

Assume I have this expressions defined:

- `{username}` shall generate `"sebhaase"`

and an expression-function

- `{highlight word}` shall generate (just for the purpose of illustration) `"<b class=hi>word</b>"`
  .

So far I was using the Python `regex` module's `sub()` to call my handler function `conv()` on everything that started with a `{` and ends with `}`.

But, can I keep using regex trying to handle `{highlight {username}}` to generate `"<b class=hi>sebhaase</b>"`

Or, do I need to look for bigger guns?
Is there any other fast Python module that could do this kind of nested string substitution.

The `regex` module supports recursion as opposed to `re` - but I don't see how/if this applies to `sub()`.

Comment: Python's regex engine doesn't support arbitrary nesting.

Comment: You *can* articulate an expression for a fixed level of nesting but it's messy and cumbersome. But simply replacing the innermost pair of braces until there are none left should be easy and elegant.

Comment: Could you use string interpolation (f-strings) as an alternative?  For instance if we had: `def highlight(w): return f"<b class=hi>{word}</b>"`.  Then with `username = "sebhaase"`.  String interpolation on `f"{highlight(username)}"` provides the desired result of `"<b class=hi>sebhaase</b>"`.  String interpolation is able to call the highlight function and interpret the parameters.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: You are correct for the standard `re` module - but I explicitly mentioned the `regex` module - https://pypi.org/project/regex - which supports recursion.

Comment: I opened an issue about this at the `regex` bitbucket repository: https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/issues/361/expand-sub-to-handle-overlapping-capture